# Friendly_id 5 slug_candidates, how to use sequential numbering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

The new version of friendly_id uses a slug_candidates method to create the slugged values appending a uuid if a duplicate is found, how do use this to get the old functionality?
i.e matching records will be appended with 1,2,3 etc.

```
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :title,
      [:title, 'code that creates a sequential number']
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a method like

```
def duplicates_count
  Model.where(title: self.title).count + 1 # Model is whatever the model is
end
```

and `slug_candidates` method would become

```
def slug_candidates
  [
    :title,
    [:title, :duplicates_count]
  ]
end
```

Would something like this work for you? Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This won't account for names with upper vs lowercase titles.